# What is the XPath of an element in a different, default namespace?

Tags: xml, xpath

I deal with this SOAP response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <StartProcessFileResponse xmlns="http://www.abbyy.com/RecognitionServer4_xml/RecognitionServer4.xml">
         <StartProcessFileResult>{B4815D0C-91F9-4BD3-BF2F-3A70E935AA7B}</StartProcessFileResult>
      </StartProcessFileResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I need to get XPath to the the `StartProcessFileResult` element, but when I try this XPath in an online XPath validator, I get no match:

```
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/StartProcessFileResponse/StartProcessFileResult
```

I tried a smaller piece of XPath and this XPath `/soap:Envelope/soap:Body` returns the `<body>` element, but when I go further and try to access `StartProcessFileResponse` with this XPath  `/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/StartProcessFileResponse`, I get no match.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StartProcessFileResult` is in the `http://www.abbyy.com/RecognitionServer4_xml/RecognitionServer4.xml` default namespace.

Using the namespace binding facilities of your XPath library, bind a namespace prefix, say `rs` to `http://www.abbyy.com/RecognitionServer4_xml/RecognitionServer4.xml`.

Then the following XPath will select the `StartProcessFileResult` as requested:

```
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/rs:StartProcessFileResponse/rs:StartProcessFileResult
```

If you cannot bind a namespace prefix, you can use the `local-name()` function instead,

```
/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/*[local-name()='StartProcessFileResponse']/*[local-name()='StartProcessFileResult']
```

but the preferred way is to make and use the namespace prefix binding.